# How use Greater Than 0 (>0) within Case in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this line in my stored procedure.

```
CreatedBy = CASE    
               WHEN @Userregisteredby = 0 THEN 0
               ELSE CreatedBy
            END
```

In my table there is either 0 or 1 or any other values  for `CreatedBy`.

I want to get only that rows with `CreatedBy=0` if I send 0 from front end radio button list.

Same way, I want to get only that rows with `CreatedBy > 0` if I send 1 from the front end. For the ELSE condition I want to get all rows. How to do this thing?

In my code, I am unable to use condition something like this:

```
WHEN @Userregisterdby = 1 Then > 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT fields FROM table 
WHERE
    (@UserRegisteredBy = 0 and CreatedBy = 0)
    or 
    (@UserRegisteredBy = 1 and CreatedBy > 0)
    or 
    (@UserRegisteredBy is null)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly you want to

- Pull all records where `CreatedBy = 0` when `@Userregisteredby = 0`
- Pull all records where `CreatedBy > 0` when `@Userregisteredby > 0`

---

```
WHERE CreatedBy = CASE 
                     -- Admin
                     WHEN @Userregisteredby = 1 AND CreatedBy > 0 THEN CreatedBy 
                     -- Self
                     WHEN @Userregisteredby = 0 THEN 0
                     -- Everyone else (exclude self/admin records)
                     WHEN CreatedBy > 1 THEN CreatedBy
                  END
```

Comment: Oh Sorry ! my Mistake . Created by can be 0 or 1 or any other Values but Not Null

Comment: 0 is For Self
1 is for by Admin
>1(any other values greater than 1)by  any one else

Comment: This Worked but For >0 it should exclude the rows with CreatedBy=0

Comment: @SantanuMaulik so `ELSE CreatedBy > 1`? Surely you would want to exclude admin records.

Comment: My Requirement was
For 0 Only Self
For >0 Admin & Others
ELSE ADMIN, SELF , OTHERS. 
BTW THANKS , I HAVE GOT THE IDEA FROM UR CODE & THE OTHER REPLY. I WOULD MANGE IT BY MYSELF. :)